# Which conferences and journals are notably trusted in the area of wireless sensor networks?

Tags: networking, sensors

I am trying to get into the field of security concerning wireless sensor networks and found several good books and papers. But still this research topic is filled with fraud publications on questionable conferences and journals. So I would like to ask a community mainly focusing on IoT devices and therefore probably also on WSNs. Which conferences and journals have a well organised review process and earned a certain amount of approval of the WSN community to be considered trustable.

Most of Indian journals/conferences on this topic (as far as I was able to evaluate) are not trustable or just plain bad. The sensors journal published by MDPI seems to be more then questionable as far as I was able to determine it by reading several papers and then researching feedback of reviewers and some authors. Reviewers on this conference seem to be pressured to finish their peer-reviews starting from the first day they received the paper to review by remembering them in an unpleasant way every single day.

I have read so many fraud papers in this area that I am starting to get frustrated, so I would be very happy if the more experienced researchers could name the most important conferences concerning wireless sensor networks and security in wireless sensor networks.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and support.